# Xamarin.Forms - iOS - If user declines notification permission and then changes manually in settings, how do I get the devicetoken?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

After installing our app we ask the user for permission to send them notifications. If they accept all works well and we get a devicetoken etc.
My question is when the user initially declines the permission request, so RegisteredForRemoteNotifications won't be called and we won't get a devicetoken. Which is understandable because he declined.
BUT if the user then manually turns on the notifications in the device settings, when will there be a devicetoken generated? I haven't been able to request the permission again, it won't show the request dialog and permission granted is automatically set to false.

I know how to check if the system notification permissions are granted, but I need the devicetoken to be set. Can anyone explain how this would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1):

> In iOS and tvOS, you initiate APNs registration for your app by
> calling the registerForRemoteNotifications method of the UIApplication
> object. Call this method at launch time as part of your normal startup
> sequence.

You get the token from `RegisteredForRemoteNotifications` method and this method will be called at launch time.

Another point you need to know is that when a user change permission manually in settings, your app will manually **restart** by iOS system.

So after user changed the setting, the app will relaunch and then get the device token.